# Passing Variables in and out of Visual Workflow

Tags: visual-workflow

I am creating a record using a visual workflow and would like to be able to open the object I created within the flow in edit mode when the user clicks on the finish button. I am using the flow:interview methods from a visualforce page.

```
<flow:interview name="Create_Project" finishLocation="{!URLFOR('/a0B/o}')}}"/>
```

I don’t seem to be able to pass an output variable to the URLFOR method.

In another example I have used the URL method to pass parameters to a flow but again I have the same problem that I cannot end up at the created object.

```
/flow/Create_Project?Account_Name_Input={!Account.Name}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Found this; does it help? I'm not aware of any non-Apex way of doing this... yet!
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000097pVIAQ

Comment: Thanks. I had seen this but was hoping for a more simple route :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a tip I got from Jeff Bloomer at https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009AgOIAU

Here's what worked for me.  I also have a flow that starts from the Account screen.  The code for my button is:

```
/apex/Customer_Service_Request?txt_AcctID={!Account.Id}
```

Then, the code I used for my Visualforce page was:

```
<apex:page >
    <flow:interview name="Customer_Service_Request" finishLocation="/{!$CurrentPage.parameters.txt_AcctID}"/>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable of type "Input" with a Unique name that matches the URL parameter.

/flow/Create_Project?**Account_Name_Input**={!Account.Name}

Variable name would be "**Account_Name_Input**"
Type defaults to Private, you must change it to "Input".  If you fail to change it, you won't see the passed value.

Answer (score 0):

The CodeFriar wrote a brilliant reusable redirect controller for Visual Flow. You only have to install it, and can re-use it for any flow. http://codefriar.com/2014/04/18/a-reusable-redirect-controller-for-visualflows/